# How to work with Vim + Pathogen + SnipMate?

Tags: vim, snippets

The problem with working out SnipMate under Pathogen is basically in adding new snippets, or a [separate snippet bundle](https://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets) under the `/bundles` directory.

Any ideas regarding a working configuration of this problem?

Comment: I use ~/.vim/bundle/snipMate/snippets/ and works fine.

Comment: Same as Eelvex, all the custom snippets I've added work very well. And are you sure you want to add all of scrooloose's snippets? A little bit of copypasta may be enough.

Comment: Thanks guys. Problem is, I store bundles as Git repositories (submodules), and I don't want to "contaminate" the repos with untracked files.

What do I do?

Comment: @romainl: how did you add your custom snippets?

Comment: @Neil G, you only need to edit the files located at `~/.vim/bundle/snipMate/snippets`. The syntax is very easy to understand. There's a little trap, though: the mandatory whitespace before each snippet is a `<Tab>`, not a double-space.

Comment: @romainl: Thanks, but I'm having the same problem as Konzepz.  Is there any way to put custom snippets in a separate file?

Comment: @Neil G, you can create a snippets folder like that: `~/.vim/snippets` and put your custom snippets there, I just tried with an actionscript snippets and it worked perfectly. I think you can also do something like `~/.vim/ftplugin/javascript/snippets/javascript.snippets` but don't take my word for it.

Comment: @romainl: So, what I want is to have additional or modified cpp.snippets in `.vim/snippets` even though there's already a cpp.snippets in `.vim/bundles/.../snippets`.  Do you think it will work?

Comment: @Neil G, according to my experience, yes. However, snipMate will complain at startup if you choose the same abbreviation as in the default `cpp.snippets`. That said, editing the default `*.snippets` files is the most straightforward way. I really have no idea why it wouldn't work. Did you quit Vim? Did you reload your configuration?

Comment: @romainl: I can edit the files, but they are git submodules and I want them to be automatically updated as new versions are released using `git submodule...`  I'd like to keep my overrides/custom cpp snippets separate from the downloaded versions.  You are right that editing would work.

Comment: @Neil G Then the `~/.vim/snippets/cpp.snippets` road seems to be the best: you won't have conflicts when updating your bundles. Another way would be to explicitly `git ignore` the files you have edited.

Comment: Maybe add this as an answer guys?

Comment: Check this out... seems to be what you want.
http://superuser.com/questions/402617/snipmate-pathogen-git-custom-snippets-dont-work-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

By default snipMate looks for snippets in ~/.vim/snippets so just put your new snippets files there or change the `g:snippets_dir` variable in Vim to any directory you want.

I have `let g:snippets_dir = "~/.vim/snippets"` in my vimrc file so snipMate only looks at my custom snippets files. If you want both then just use the defaults + the ~/.vim/snippets directory.

Answer (score 0):

For pathogen, you can simple use git and add a submodule liket his:

```
 git submodule add https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate ~/.vim/bundle/snipmate
```

Check out [garab's `vim-snipmate` github](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate).