# Snipmate + Pathogen + Git - Custom Snippets don't work on Windows

Tags: vim, gvim, vim-plugins, snippets

Here is my setup:

1. My .vim directory is under source control with git
2. I use Pathogen for managing my plugins
3. My SnipMate plugin is a git submodule under `.vim/bundle/snipmate`

This means I can't really edit the snippets in `.vim/bundle/snipmate/snippets` because they are not tracked. I have discovered that I can define my own custom snippets in `.vim/snippets`, or create a new directory `.vim/bundle/snipmate-custom/snippets/` and define them there.

This works beautifully on linux. For example I can have the original file `html.snippets` in `.vim/bundle/snipmate/snippets` and my own `html.snippets` in `.vim/snippets/` and vim will use both files.

On Windows I have noticed that creating another snippets directory (either in `.vim/snippets/` or in `.vim/bundle/snipmate-custom/snippets/` breaks the plugin. The tab completion no longer works - it ignores both the original snippets that came with the plugin, and the ones in the new repository.

Any idea why this is happening?

I'm running Vista, and I my vim config is in `%USERPROFILE%\.vim`. I have vimfiles folder symlinked to that directory using:

`mklink /d vimfiles .vim`

Every other plugin works. Shipmate works perfectly provided the `.vim/snippets` directory does not exist. The above setup works fine on Ubuntu and on Mac. Any idea why it breaks on Windows?

**EDIT**

I might have answered my own question. I managed to work around this problem by explicitly telling snipmate which directories to use:

```
   if has('win32')
      let g:snippets_dir="c:/Users/me/.vim/bundle/snipmate/snippets/,
                          c:/Users/me/.vim/bundle/snipmate-custom/snippets"
   endif
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works. Let me know if you figure out a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question. I managed to work around this problem by explicitly telling snipmate which directories to use:

```
   if has('win32')
      let g:snippets_dir="c:/Users/me/.vim/bundle/snipmate/snippets/,
                          c:/Users/me/.vim/bundle/snipmate-custom/snippets"
   endif
```